# Что такое контекстные синонимы?

Tags: лексика

Что это такое?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Синонимы - это слова, близкие или тождественные по значению . Контекстные синонимы - это слова, которые являются синонимами только в данном  контексте. Например, слова студент и юноша в языке не синонимы. А в тексте вполне могут таковыми быть.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно контекстные синонимы выступают как тождественные по лексическому значению только в контексте. Чтобы определить, что они таковыми являются, можно к ним подобрать одно общее по лексическому значению слово, общий синоним. Например, у тебя некрасивая, ужасная, корявая речь. Все эти прилагательные являются синонимами только в данном контексте. К ним можно подобрать один общий синоним "безграмотная", т.е. не соответствующая речевым нормам. Понятно, что в отрыве от контекста слова "некрасивая" и "корявая" синонимами являться не будут.